# I am trying to run java application in Eclipse, When I try to do Run > Run as > Java Application it starts to show little processing but nothing happe

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, configuration, compilation

I am running my first Spring based project where I was trying to execute this class but as I mentioned, it shows me some processing and nothing happens.

My `App.java` code ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV36W.png)):

```java
package in.gautamiShetty.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }
}
```

I tried searching for the solution, where I checked my main method, tried to rerun it as java application. I would really be thankful if someone finds the solution for this problem

Comment: `ApplicationContext ctxt = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);` creates only the context. The main method needs to contain something like `SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);` (see e.g. [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service#_run_the_service)). Consider to follow one of the [Getting Started Guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs).